# Cancel command: color, verse, number of lines

Tags: cancel

I need a command like `\cancel{}`  but with more '' options '':

- change the cancel color
- the number of the line that cancel the text
- compatible with math mode
- change the direction of the line

[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean with “change the verse”?  Also, `\cancel` is mostly compatible with maths mode, are you having a specific problem?  Have a look at other question about `\cancel` on this site, especially the ones recommending solutions with TikZ, they may already do what you’re asking for.

Comment: In the figure, the cancel in black have a different verse from the red cancel.

Comment: Oh God, you mean direction.  Got it.  That is *not* what verse means.

Comment: to get the red ones why don't you use \bcancel{} that is within the cancel package

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/105905/19326 for the color bit