# use CancelColor in mathjax

Tags: mathjax

I want to use `\cancel{·}` in mathjax. with a crossed line of different color, explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105902/cancel-with-different-colors).

I use

```
\[
enter code here
\require{xcolor}
\require{cancel}
\renewcommand\CancelColor{\color{red}}

\cancel{x^2}
\]
```

But is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, welcome on TeX.SE! Please note that mathjax is [borderline off-topic here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/mathjax/info). If no-one answers please consider asking it on stackoverflow.com instead.

Comment: yes, I realized, but I thought it would be the best option. I will follow your advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
\newcommand\ccancel[2][black]{\color{#1}{\cancel{\color{black}{#2}}}}
```

so that

```
\ccancel[red]{x}
```

would use a red slash through a black *x*.

Comment: I still find appalling that MathJax uses `\color` as a substitute for `\textcolor`. It should be changed. Maybe too late, but if you want to imagine interchangeable code for MathJax and LaTeX, this is a stopping.

Comment: I am not aware of `\textcolor`,  but the interchangeability is not important this time. Brilliant

Comment: @egreg, the MathJax `color` extension gets you a more LaTeX-compatible version of `\color` that includes `\textcolor` and several other macros, and makes `\color` act like a switch rather than taking an argument for what to color.  You can include it in a MathJax configuration if you are managing your own page, or use `\require{color}` to load it if not.  There is unfortunate history (and ignorance on my part) behind this use of `\color`.